# Hold tableView data for specific Index, which is been tapped using Tap gesture but not using didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing an issue with `UITableVIew`, lets say I have a screen with tableView having three images in its **resuablecell** cell also contains some text, I want to open that image as a popup to view larger so added `UITapGesture`, and for opening that I am passing image reference like this,

```
@objc func showImage (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("ImageTapped")

        let imagePopupVC: ImagePopupViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imagePopupVC") as! ImagePopupViewController
        imagePopupVC.isImage = true
        if popUpFeedImage != nil {
            // here this feedImage is the one i am passing to other VC
            imagePopupVC.image = popUpFeedImage
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePopupVC, animated: false)
    }
```

and here i am getting this `popUpFeedImage` populated, in `cellForRowAt`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: MemberTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MemberTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MemberTableViewCell
let urlString: URL = URL(string: postContent.contentURL)!
         let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showImage(_:)))
        cell.feedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.feedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

                    cell.feedImageView.sd_setImage(with: urlString, placeholderImage: nil) { (image, error, imageCacheType, url) in
                        self.popUpFeedImage = image
                    }
}
```

Now where the issue has come, as this image is been populated and I tap the 1st image it opens the image which is the last image in the cell which is 3rd one, and happens for all which image is been displayed in last of screen will display, now I have no idea to hold that reference for the image i have tapped on specific `Index`, 
I have implemented `didSelectItemAt` for opening another `viewController`, so i can not use this for my this specific purpose.
Any help would be helpful thanks.

Comment: I don't see how both snippets are related since they aren't called in each other. Please explain this in depth. Also, why are you not using the `indexPath` for determining which image to put per cell?

Comment: yes sorry forgot to mention tapGesture code, now have a look i have updated the question.

Comment: What does `sd_setImage` do? Is it an escaping closure? Please insert that snippet here

Comment: its a library which converts url to image and that image i am giving to `popUpFeedImage` it is the whole closure.

Comment: First of all move your tap gesture code inside cell class then create an method that returns selected image.Second thing all cell contains 3 images or one?

Comment: Have you got that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your image from tapped view inside gesture recognizer handling method:

```
@objc func showImage (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("ImageTapped")

    guard let tappedView = sender.view else { return }

    if let imageView = tappedView as? UIImageView {
        self.popUpFeedImage = imageView.image
    } else {

        tappedView.subviews.forEach { subView in

            if subView.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) {
                self.popUpFeedImage = subView.image
            }
        }
    }

    let imagePopupVC: ImagePopupViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imagePopupVC") as! ImagePopupViewController
    imagePopupVC.isImage = true
    if popUpFeedImage != nil {
        // here this feedImage is the one i am passing to other VC
        imagePopupVC.image = popUpFeedImage
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePopupVC, animated: false)
}
```

Or you can specify tag number to your imageViews and when you want to get image just compare tapped view id and imageView id.